# SQL transactional replication - cannot drop table as referred to by indexed view which I cannot replicate

Tags: sql, replication, dynamics-nav

I'm trying to get transactional replication of a MS NAV database working on a couple of SQL 2008 R2 servers.

I was able to get the replication working, however running any kind of CREATE or ALTER operation on the inexed views causes the NAV application to fail (error below). The indexed views would be static between major version releases, so don't really need to be replicated.

I set up replication again, this time not including the indexed views, however I'm now encountering the following  error:

"Replication-Replication Distribution Subsystem: agent [SQLSRV01\NAV SQLSRV02\NAV] failed. Cannot DROP TABLE '[Table]' because it is being referenced by object '[Indexed view referencing table]'."

So, bit of a pain. I'm a little confused why the replication system is trying to drop the table anyway, unless it's rebuilding the entire database on the subscription server. 
Any suggestions where to go from here would be very welcome - I obviously want to have all my tables replicated, but these references of indexed fields are causing a lot of problems (but need to stay).

Out of interest, if I run an 'ALTER VIEW' over an indexed view, but don't change anything, this is the sort of error I get when I try to access that table via the Dynamics NAV client:

[image: Error]

Comment: Are you using the GUI to configure replication, or are you running sql  scripts to setup your publications and subscriptions?

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the response. I'm using the GUI to set up the replication.